# C++ cannot convert from enum to LPCTSTR

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I compile game source code in Visual Studio and found some error while compile.

> error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from
>   'eKind' to 'LPCTSTR'
>   Conversion from integral type to pointer type requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast

```
enum eKind
{
        NONE,
        CONSO,  //consonant
        V_UP,   //vowel in upper
        SV_UP,  //special vowel in upper
        V_SIDE, //vowel in side
        V_UN,   //vowel in under
        V_UPSI, //vowel in upper and side
        SOU,    //special in upper
        ENG,    //english and number
}
LastKind = NONE;

LPCTSTR thai[255] = {
        NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,
        NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,
        NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,
        ENG,    ENG,    ENG,    ENG,    ENG,    ENG,    ENG,    ENG,    ENG,    ENG,    NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,
        NONE,   ENG,    ENG,    ENG,    ENG,    ENG,    ENG,    ENG,    ENG,    ENG,    ENG,    ENG,    ENG,    ENG,    ENG,    ENG,
        ENG,    ENG,    ENG,    ENG,    ENG,    ENG,    ENG,    ENG,    ENG,    ENG,    ENG,    NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,
        NONE,   ENG,    ENG,    ENG,    ENG,    ENG,    ENG,    ENG,    ENG,    ENG,    ENG,    ENG,    ENG,    ENG,    ENG,    ENG,
        ENG,    ENG,    ENG,    ENG,    ENG,    ENG,    ENG,    ENG,    ENG,    ENG,    ENG,    NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,
        NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,
        NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,

        NONE,   CONSO,  CONSO,  CONSO,  CONSO,  CONSO,  CONSO,  CONSO,  CONSO,  CONSO,  CONSO,  CONSO,  CONSO,  CONSO,  CONSO,  CONSO,
        CONSO,  CONSO,  CONSO,  CONSO,  CONSO,  CONSO,  CONSO,  CONSO,  CONSO,  CONSO,  CONSO,  CONSO,  CONSO,  CONSO,  CONSO,  CONSO,
        CONSO,  CONSO,  CONSO,  CONSO,  CONSO,  CONSO,  CONSO,  CONSO,  CONSO,  CONSO,  CONSO,  CONSO,  CONSO,  CONSO,  CONSO,  CONSO,

        V_SIDE, V_UP,   V_SIDE, V_UPSI, V_UP,   V_UP,   V_UP,   V_UP,   V_UN,   V_UN,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,
        V_SIDE, V_SIDE, V_SIDE, V_SIDE, V_SIDE, V_SIDE, V_SIDE, SV_UP,  SOU,    SOU,    SOU,    SOU,    SOU,    NONE,   NONE,   NONE,
        NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE,   NONE
};
```

What's the problem? How to solve this?

Comment: What part of the error message is unclear? They are different data types. One is an integer, and one is a C-style string. Do you understand why `int x = "omg";` is an error?

Comment: Enum are internal Integer. So you cannot convert them to a pointer of strings (LPCTSTR)

Comment: -1 no example code in the question

Comment: You can see code in pastebin link. I can't post in this thread because the code format will lose.

Comment: @alexbuisson Thanks, I will convert it to correct type.

Comment: @StdAfx You could read all the StackOverflow help. If you are impatient you can: -enter the code, -select the code, and - clickt at `{}` above the text entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `enum` is a scalar data type. `LPCTSTR` is a typedef of a pointer to `char` or `wchar_t` (depends on Unicode setting).

C++ does not allow the implicit conversion from a scalar to a pointer. Use an appropriate source data type to assign it to a `LPCTSTR`.

In your example you want to define an array of `TCHAR` instead of a pointer to it.

```
TCHAR thai[255] = {
    NONE,   NONE,  
    // ...
};
```

Comment: Thanks you for your help. I will change data type. :)

Answer (score 1):

Unlike C#, for example, you can get a string representation of an enum in C/C++. If you want to so this sort of thing you'll need to write the some yourself. For example:

```
std::string eKindToString(eKind value)
{
  switch(value)
  {
    case foo: return "foo";
    case bar: return "bar";
    // etc
  }

  return "unknown";
}
```

Comment: Can't see that an enum->string conversion is desired. Did I miss something?

Comment: I think it's because you can use `std::string::c_str()` or `std::wstring::c_str()` afterwards

Comment: Yes, your code shows how to circumvent the missing reflection capabilities of C++. But I didn't find this in the question.